# PopupWindow not showing

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I have founded many solutions for this problem but none of them have worked for me. I want to show a PopupWindow inside a Fragment. This is my code

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_cargando, null,false);
this.popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, popupView.getWidth(),popupView.getHeight());
this.popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
int location[] = new int[2];
this.btnInventario.getLocationOnScreen(location);
this.popupWindow.showAtLocation(this.btnInventario, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, location[0], location[1] + btnInventario.getHeight()); // this.btnInventario is the button that calls this code
this.popupWindow.update(0, 0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

But the PopupWindow never appears.

Edit: This is the content of pop_up_cargando

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_recomendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/cargando"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTexto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/vacio"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions? What I'm doing wrong? Your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm using popupWindow.showAtLocation. It's in the code

Comment: Check that the `popupView.getWidth()` and `popupView.getHeight()` values are greater than 0.

Comment: @G.T. both are 0... didn't notice that. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `popupView.getWidth()` and `popupView.getHeight()` values are equals to 0 because the view has not been drawn yet.

Before asking for the *width* and the *height* of your view, you have to ensure that it has been drawn. For that you can call the following method after it has been inflated:

```
popupView.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

After that, the size of your view is available with the methods `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Added those lines. Now it's taking the correct values for height and width, but the popup still doesn't appear...

Comment: What if you replace the last two lines by `popupWindow.show()`?

Comment: Can't: "The method show() is undefined for the type PopupWindow"

Comment: Indeed... my bad. Try to hard code values in showAtLocation